# How to use new enhanced sessions in Parse with users created on cloud code?

Tags: rest, session, parse-platform

I was trying out the new enhanced revocable sessions in Parse on my Android app. It works well when logging in or signing up via email password or facebook but doesn't work well for custom authentication, e.g. google+.

I'm currently logging in the user using the cloud code which also creates the new user when signing up. This does not create a new Session object, that means the new enhanced sessions are not used and it still uses the legacy sessions.

I pass the session token back to client where using the become method the user logs in but it's the legacy sessions.

This feels like the feature is not complete but I would really like to move to the new enhanced sessions with my app. Has anyone worked with them yet? Are there any workarounds using the [REST API](https://www.parse.com/docs/rest#summary) or by creating the sessions manually and handling them manually? I looked into the JS API but it says it's only read only.

Here's the [Blog post on Enhanced Sessions](http://blog.parse.com/2015/03/25/announcing-new-enhanced-sessions/).

Where should I go next?

Comment: Have you seen the [Parse Session Migration Tutorial](https://parse.com/tutorials/session-migration-tutorial)? It seems to be what you're looking for.

Comment: @DavidRobinson Yes, I've seen this tutorial. It doesn't tell about how to use enhanced sessions with custom authentication. Am i missing something? Many people are facing this problem.

Comment: Also wondering about this. Apparently you can create custom Parse.Session objects, but these are restricted (loT). Is there a way around this?

Comment: Did you get manage this? I'm stuck with this now...

Comment: @Arturo No I couldn't, I will get back to it in a few weeks now. If you find a solution, please post an answer.

Comment: @droidster if you get managed this please post your answer as we're on a really tight deadline and we can't seem to find a solution anywhere. Thanks!"

Comment: @gopal_patil I couldn't find any solution. It would be best to migrate off Parse asap.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I found a solution but it's a workaround, works for my case because I don't support signing up with user/password.

Basically, the solution (cloud code) in semi pseudo-code is:

1. Fetch the user with master key
2. Check if `user.getSessionToken()` has value
3. if it has, return the session token and do a `user.become()` in the client as usual
4. if it's not, here the workaround, do the following:

```js
  yourPreviousPromiseInOrderToChainThem.then(function(user) 
    password = new Buffer(24);
    _.times(24, function(i) {
      password.set(i, _.random(0, 255));
    });
    password = password.toString('base64')
    user.setPassword(password);
    return user.save();
  }).then(function(user) {
    return Parse.User.logIn(user.get('username'), password)
  }).then(function(user) {
    var sessionToken = user.getSessionToken();
    // Return the session token to the client as you've been doing with legacy sessions
  })
```

That means, I'm **changing the user password each time** in order to make a remote login and, of course, I know thist can't be applied to all cases, it's enough for app because I don't support login with user/password (only third party logins) but I understand that maybe it's not for all cases.
I got the idea from this official [Parse example](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/CloudCodeOAuthGitHubTutorial).

I don't like this solution because I think is not a workaround, it's a **mega hack** but I think **there is no other way** to do it currently (either [Parse.com](http://www.parse.com) or [Parse-Server](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server))

If you find other workaround, please, share it :)

Comment: Aah yeah, it's a hack. Thanks for posting. I'll try to find something in a few weeks when we eventually decide to do this. I'll post if I find something.

Comment: @arturo  i am using this approach but getting can not modify user for parse server.

Comment: @arturo Do you have any suggestions? We're on a really tight deadline and we can't seem to find a solution anywhere. Thanks!

Comment: I didn't search about  this problem anymore that this workaround fits perfect for my use-case but I agree that we need a right solution to avoid this hack...